# Moving trailing 13-week average in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to build a view that generates a movable 13-week average over the past year.

My source data includes a date, customer ID, and integer, and basically I want to average the 13 prior values (including the current one), over the previous 52 weeks. When I'm finished, I'd like to have a table with a date, each customer ID, and trailing 13-week average for that customer.

Comment: FYI, I'm running Postgres 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading Postgres to 9.1, the window functions worked great for this:

```
SELECT vs.weekending,
cs.slinkcust AS customer,
cs.slinkid AS id,
round(avg(vs.maxattached) OVER (PARTITION BY cs.slinkid ORDER BY vs.weekending DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 12 FOLLOWING), 2) AS rolling_conc_avg,
round(avg(vs.totsessions) OVER (PARTITION BY cs.slinkid ORDER BY vs.weekending DESC ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING AND 12 FOLLOWING), 2) AS rolling_sess_avg,
dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY vs.weekending) AS week_number 
FROM cfg_slink cs
     JOIN view_statslink vs ON cs.slinkid = vs.id
  WHERE vs.weekending >= (now() - '364 days'::interval) AND cs.disabled = 0
  GROUP BY vs.weekending, cs.slinkid, vs.maxattached, vs.totsessions
  ORDER BY vs.weekending DESC, cs.slinkcust;
```